# Calculate the time to pull data from the database

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i Calculate the time it took for the "order" to pull 
all the Data "Product"  that is  found in SqlServer ?

That is, knowing the time the request takes to be fetched from Sql Server.

productController.js:

```
      const Product = require('../Models/productModel');
      const express=require('express');
      const takeData = async(req, res) => {    
      const dbResult =await Product.findAll(req.Product)
      const allProducts = dbResult.recordset;
      return res.status(200).json({message: '', products: allProducts})   
      }
      module.exports = {
      takeData:takeData
      }
```

productModel.js:

```
           const UniqueId = require('uniqid');
           const SingletonSqlHandler = require('../SQLServer/singleton');
           class Product {
           constructor(ProductName, Price) {
           this.ProductID = UniqueId();
           this.ProductName=ProductName;
           this.Price=Price
           }
           static async findAll(ProductID) {
           const Pull_Products=await 
           SingletonSqlHandler.instance.sendQuery('SELECT * from 
           dbo.getAllProducts()')        
           return Pull_Products;
           }
           }
           module.exports = Product
```

productRoute.js:

```
   const router = require('express').Router();
   const productController=require('../Controllers/productController')
   router.get('/takeData', productController.takeData);
   module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please put some code .Are you using callbacks ,promises or async await to pull the data ?

Comment: @Shubh I edit it,Where can I add the code (the code you put down below) in my code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `console.time("label")` .It takes a label and when you want to end to check ,how much time has been passed do  `console.timeEnd("label")`.

```js
console.time("answer time");

setTimeout(()=>{
 
  console.timeEnd("answer time");

},1000)
```

In your code you can do lke this

```
const Product = require('../Models/productModel');
      const express=require('express');
      const takeData = async(req, res) => { 

       console.time("answer time");   

       const dbResult =await Product.findAll(req.Product)

       console.timeEnd("answer time");

      const allProducts = dbResult.recordset;
      return res.status(200).json({message: '', products: allProducts})   
      }
      module.exports = {
      takeData:takeData
      }
```

Documentation

[console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time)

[console.timeEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd)

Comment: Thank you for your Answer , Where can I add it to the code? @Shubh

Comment: Updated the answer @NourGeorge please check

Comment: Thank you for your Answer ,My problem was solved by your answer, but I Have Question :
Why when I execute multiple times behind each other, I get different times despite the same request and the same data that I pull from the DataBase, for example the first time I sent the request the answer was:
answer time: 10596.642ms

and the second time :
answer time: 1643.831ms

and the Third Time :
answer time: 498.623ms

Comment: That's actually because of event loop in node js .Like eventloop is at which stage of the eventloop queue

Comment: Read these articles -https://blog.insiderattack.net/event-loop-and-the-big-picture-nodejs-event-loop-part-1-1cb67a182810